# What does "lock" boolean mean in GenericHibernateDAO's method findById?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate. When i have to find a specific entity, i want to use the 
    findById(Long id, boolean lock)

method. What value should i give to lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for the method is [here](http://el4j.sourceforge.net/framework-modules/apidocs/ch/elca/el4j/services/persistence/hibernate/dao/GenericHibernateDao.html#findById(ID,%20boolean)).  You should put true if you want no chance of the value changing while you are getting  it from the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, the data i will get never change. So, there is no difference whatever value i give. Is that right?

Comment: Just give it a false if that's the case.  It'll make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

There are several overloaded findById. You should choose one depending on the locking strategy you are using.

I suggest read about optimist and pessimist locking.